# How should I improve Training and Validation Accuracy/Loss?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, ocr, conv-neural-network

I am training a model for Optical Character Recognition of Gujarati Language. Ihe input image is a character image. I have taken 20 classes. Total training images are 12000 (600 per class) and testing images are 3200 (160 per class).

How should I improve my accuracy and reduce loss?

Below is my code:

```
    classifier = Sequential()


# Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (32, 32, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())

# Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))




# Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 1024, activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 20, activation = 'softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

classifier.summary()

# Fitting the CNN to the images

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   
                                   
                                   horizontal_flip=False)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = False)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/shweta/Desktop/characters/train',
                                                 target_size = (32, 32),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/shweta/Desktop/characters/test',
                                            target_size = (32, 32),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')


classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                        
                         epochs = 22,
                         validation_data = test_set, shuffle=True)
classifier.save('alphanumeric.mod')
```

Output:

```
Epoch 19/22
375/375 [==============================] - 34s 89ms/step - loss: 0.1800 - accuracy: 0.9414 - val_loss: 0.1945 - val_accuracy: 0.9397
Epoch 20/22
375/375 [==============================] - 34s 91ms/step - loss: 0.1729 - accuracy: 0.9445 - val_loss: 0.6013 - val_accuracy: 0.8450
Epoch 21/22
375/375 [==============================] - 34s 91ms/step - loss: 0.1798 - accuracy: 0.9420 - val_loss: 0.1817 - val_accuracy: 0.9409
Epoch 22/22
375/375 [==============================] - 35s 93ms/step - loss: 0.1802 - accuracy: 0.9398 - val_loss: 0.1757 - val_accuracy: 0.9425
```

Comment: Shouldn't the final dense layer have 10 units instead of 20 because you only have 10 classes?

Comment: sorry,Actually i had 20 classes to train. My typo mistake in the question

Comment: What results are you expecting? The accuracies seem reasonable to me.

Comment: I think you should try to add more Conv2D layers and reduce one or more Dense layers, augmentate data by using rotate, shift, flip, scale,... Also use BatchNorm layers to increase model stable at training time.

Comment: I am training my model for OCR of Gujarati language characters.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the nature of the dataset, it is difficult to help too much.

Here are a few of my observations. Deep convolutional neural networks usually only have one dense softmax layer, and 4 layers shouldn't increase accuracy significantly. Consider using more convolutional layers if the data is featureful, and a single dense layer. Finally, add batch normalization before the first convolutional layer and following each layer. Other techniques such as bayesian optimization can also be applied, but they are significantly more work for likely a small improvement.

Comment: I have added batch normalization and obtained the accuracy. Have a look. I edited the question. What parameters do i need to change of batch normalization to improve my validation accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some things wrong in your code. Looking at the training and validation accuracy which are pretty close, this means that your model is not suffering from hight variance. It may or may not suffer from high bias. This depends on what the bayes error is (which I don't know for this particular task but it is probably lower than the one that you have achieved assuming that you have reasonable data).

Assuming that your model is really suffering from high bias, you can try increasing the complexity of the model until it starts to overfit the data.

For example, you can try to replace your `Conv2D` layers/blocks with

```
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same"))
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="valid"))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(ReLU())                             #keras.layers.ReLU
classifier.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="valid"))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(ReLU())                             #keras.layers.ReLU
classifier.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
classifier.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="valid"))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(ReLU())                             #keras.layers.ReLU
classifier.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
```

Few things to note here:

1. as you are going deeper into the network, the size of the image will shrink due to either `valid` padding, stride, and/or pooling. At the same time, you should be increasing the number of filters, something like (32 -> 64 -> 128 -> ...). This is not a hard rule but it tends to work better than keeping the number of filters the same - you are using 32 filters in all your convolutional layers.
2. Batch normalization should be applied on the linear output of the layer (pre-activation) not on the post-activation as you are implementing it right now. So you should have `z` -> batch-norm -> `a` where `z` is the linear output of the layer (in your case `Conv2D`) and `a` is the activation of the layer so your need to split this into multiple "layers" (in Keras terminology).

```
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="valid")) # no activation here
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(ReLU())
```

3. You don't probably need such a huge `Dense` layer at the top. It will increase training time without much of a benefit (one or two smaller Dense layers should be ok).
4. you should also try training longer while gradually reducing the learning rate, this can often reduce the loss. You can just recompile your model with optimizer set to `keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=...)` instead of just string `"adam"` to specify the learning rate (and possibly other optimizer hyperparameters but the defaults usually work just fine). Note that setting the correct learning rate is one of the most important factors when training neural network, and can have a dramatic impact on its performance - don't just rely on the default value.

Comment: hey Thanks!  This code worked well and i reached the accuracy of 96% with some fluctuations.

Comment: Can i further apply the concept of mini-batch for further increasing validation accuracy?!

Comment: mini-batch size affects the speed at which you train your model, not the accuracy (at least not directly). You can play around with the batch size but I would not expect it to increase the accuracy of your model in any significant way (if you are training for long enough already).

Comment: I have to extend my code to train on around 600 characters i.e 600 classes.

Comment: I can also try some network like AlexNet or DenseNet. What you suggest?

Comment: Architecturally or for transfer learning? If architecturaly, these are rather complex networks and you will need a ton of training examples to make it work which you probably don't have at hand. If for transfer learning, then I would suggest getting familiar with transfer learning at first because there are little details that matter a lot and if you get them wrong, your new network might underperform a lot (i.e. freezing/unfreezing, when to unfreeze, how to set learning rate when the CNN base is frozen and when it isn't, size of the pretrained CNN base to pick...).

Comment: I have to train my model on 663 classes in total with 600 training images for each class and 160 testing images for each class. Wouldn't that suffice using the network architecturally?!

Comment: Previously you have said that you have `12000 total training images`. Anyway, if you enough data then you can try whatever architecture you like. It is hard to tell which one will work better upfront. Also, it depends on the goal of your task, if accuracy is all you care about then the best possible result will be achieved by building huge ensemble of networks (stacked/voting classifiers...) but these systems are largely unmaintainable and cannot be retrainied as necessary. So, if your goal is accuracy at all costs then start traning more networks and combine them.

Comment: My goal is to train my model on 663 classes but for a start I trained my model on 20 classes to just check on the accuracy. Now I will further increase my dataset. My goal is accuracy at all costs.  What do you exactly mean by combining networks? Can u expatiate please!!

Comment: Search for how to win Kaggle competition, that is basically about improving some metric at all costs. What I mean is that if you train not one but 100 networks and combine their output (i.e. average all the 100 outputs per input...) you will most likely get superior results. Search for how to build voting/stacked classifiers and things like those. But these models are generally unusable in production due to their complexity.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by working on CPU. Technically yes, there is no operation there that couldn't be handled by CPU. This is just a function of time. I would generally not recommend training even single deep CNN (and RNN) on CPU as this will take just too much time, compared to training on GPU/TPU. When training multiple such models, this difference will just get multiplied so it is up to you how much time you want to spend on this task (and/or money depending on where you are running the training job).

Comment: ohh okay! Got it!!

Comment: Should I use Transfer Learning or train the DenseNet (which i am going to use) from scratch?